# Please help- brown patches on my Dracaena?

Tags: plant-health, dracaena

I’m quite concerned about my White Jewel Dracaena, and I was hoping to get some answers if anyone is willing to help. It has brown, rough-feeling patches on many of the leaves. It’s potted in regular potting soil, never been fertilized (I’ve only had it for a few weeks), and receives indirect bright light. I have over 35 plants currently and have honestly never seen this before... Hoping it’s not too serious? I water this guy when the soil is dry. I try to keep it in a decent amount of humidity as well. All of my plants are watered with spring water (with the exception of a few that get distilled!). 
You can see some brown spots/leaf tips on the plant, but those were unfortunately present when I bought the plant because it wasn’t really getting much water. I’m only really concerned about the dry brown patches... It seems to be curling at the edges where these brown patches are present. Any input is greatly appreciated!!! :) Thanks![image][image][image]

Comment: When did the patches appear? Were there changes in temperature, sun, etc.? They look like sun damage